Blazor - Select all checkboxes with non-boolean @bind value
I am trying to generated a dynamic list of checkboxes that will be data bound to the Guid property from a Dictionary<Guid, string> variable. Then I have a separate "Select All" checkbox which will select all the checkboxes in the list. The IDs from the selected checkboxes will be stored a variable to be used in a query. The below code seems to set the IsSelected property of each checkbox just fine when I am debugging, but the screen is not re-rendering to display the new state. I am calling Invoke in the property setter, and calling StateHasChanged() in the parent component, but still there is no visible change. What am I missing?
ParentComponent.razor
<CustomCheckbox Label="Select All" @bind-Value="@IsAllBranchesSelected" @onchange="SelectAllBranchesChanged" style="margin-bottom:25px" />

<hr style="margin: 0px 0px 3px 0px;" />

@if (AdvancedSearchBranches != null && AdvancedSearchBranches.Any())
{
    @if (Checkboxes != null && Checkboxes.Any())
    {
        @foreach (CheckBoxItemComponent cb in Checkboxes)
        {
            <CheckBoxItemComponent Value="@cb.Value" Text="@cb.Text" OnChange="Changed" />
        }
    }  
}

@code {

public List<string> AdvancedSearchBranchIds = new List<string>();
public Dictionary<Guid, string> AdvancedSearchBranches = [];
public bool? IsAllBranchesSelected = false;
List<CheckBoxItemComponent> Checkboxes = new List<CheckBoxItemComponent>();

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   LoadData();
}

private async void LoadData()
{ 
    await GetBranchesAsync();

    StateHasChanged();
}

private async Task GetBranchesAsync()
{
    if (AdvancedSearchBranches.Any())
    {
        return;
    }

    Dictionary<Guid, string> _branches = await MyData.GetBranchesByCategoryAsync(Category);

    AdvancedSearchBranches = _branches;

    // create place holders in the list that will be replaced  by the actual controls when the page renders
    foreach (var item in AdvancedSearchBranches)
    {
        Checkboxes.Add(new CheckBoxItemComponent()
            {
                Value = item.Key.ToString(),
                Text = item.Value,
                Checked = false
            });
    }
}

    public async Task SelectAllBranchesChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        //select or unselect all
        bool isSelected = e.Value as bool? ?? false;
        foreach (var item in AdvancedSearchBranches)
        {
            string branchId = item.Key.ToString();
            CheckBoxItemComponent? x = Checkboxes.Where(c => c.Value == branchId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)
            {
                // This is getting set correctly, just not rendering
                x.Checked = isSelected; 
                if (x.Checked)
                {
                    if (!AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Contains(branchId))
                    {
                        AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Add(branchId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Contains(branchId))
                    {
                        AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Remove(branchId);
                    }
                }           
            }
        }
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Changed()
    {
        foreach (var item in AdvancedSearchBranches)
        {
            string branchId = item.Key.ToString();
            CheckBoxItemComponent? x = Checkboxes.Where(c => c.Value == branchId).FirstOrDefault();
            if (x != null)
            {
                x.Checked = !x.Checked;

                if (x.Checked)
                {
                    if (!AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Contains(branchId))
                    {
                        AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Add(branchId);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Contains(branchId))
                    {
                        AdvancedSearchBranchIds.Remove(branchId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



}


CheckBoxItemComponent.razor
<input type="checkbox" @bind="@Checked" />@Text
<br />

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Action? OnChange { get; set; }

    private bool _Checked = false;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get
        {
            return _Checked;
        }
        set
        {
            _Checked = value;
            OnChange?.Invoke(); 
        }
    }
}`



There's a dead end at OnChange="Changed"

Thanks. I didn't include that method because it wasn't involved in the select all functionality, but I just added it for clarification.

It's impossible to build a Demo MRE from your code, so here's a single page demo showing the basics of what I think you are trying to achieve.  You should be able to take this and build out your page.
Note I've created a state object and collection to manage the state.  Manually creating instances of components is very wrong.   You load the state object at  start up.  You read and transpose the state data into your database object when you want to save the data.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach (var checkBoxState in _checkBoxStates)
{
    <div class="mb-2">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" @bind="checkBoxState.IsChecked" />
        @checkBoxState.Text
    </div>
}
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="this.OnSelectAll">Select All</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="this.OnDeselectAll">Deselect All</button>
</div>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-1 p-1">
    <pre>Selected Items:</pre>
    @foreach (var item in _selectedItems)
    {
        <pre>@item</pre>
    }
</div>

@code {
    private List<CheckBoxState> _checkBoxStates = new List<CheckBoxState>();

    private IEnumerable<string?> _selectedItems => _checkBoxStates.Where(x => x.IsChecked).Select(x => x.Text) ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        // load data and transfer to _checkBoxStates
        _checkBoxStates = new List<CheckBoxState>
        {
            new CheckBoxState { Value = "1", Text = "One", IsChecked = false },
            new CheckBoxState { Value = "2", Text = "Two", IsChecked = true },
            new CheckBoxState { Value = "3", Text = "Three", IsChecked = true },
        };
    }

    private void OnSelectAll()
    {
        _checkBoxStates.ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = true);
    }

    private void OnDeselectAll()
    {
        _checkBoxStates.ForEach(x => x.IsChecked = false);
    }

    public class CheckBoxState
    {
        public string? Value { get; set; }
        public string? Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}


Perfect, thank you!


What am I missing?

A click is registered with _Checked = value;. But _Checked is only accessible as a public property of the component, and there is no way for the parent to get that.
The proper way to do 2-way binding is to change OnChange from an Action to an EventCallback<bool>. See for example this answer.
When you use EventCallback right you can remove moste of those StateHasChanged calls. Always a bad sign when you see those all over the place.

new CheckBoxItemComponent()

This is always wrong - components are created and managed by the renderer.
You have here an array of components that are not on the screen.

Thank you but I don't see how this addresses my goal. I looked at the link you posted and it only works with booleans values. I need the checkboxes to be bound o the IDs from my dictionary, so when they are selected (either via Select All or selected individually), I can grab those selected IDs for my filter.

No, this is not about addressing your goal. It's about steering you away from the current approach. Your goal isn't very clear.

Sorry I wasn't clear. I have a Select All checkbox that, when selected, should check all the  checkboxes that are bound to a dictionary containing the ID and Text to be displayed. So my method SelectAllBranchesChanged needs to somehow reference the dynamic checkboxes and check them (or uncheck them).
Does that make sense?
